# How can I run "tail -f" on all log files in the current directory — except for one?

Tags: command-line, terminal, shell-script

As part of my daily dev tasks (on a Mac running OS 10.12.3) I run `tail -f *` in my log folder from Terminal. The folder contains about 15 different files. How can I alter this command to monitor changes to *all files but one* from `*`? Suppose the only file I'd like to exclude from `*` is called `Repetitive.log`.

Apologies for the very basic question, I looked around for it and didn't see a duplicate. Reposted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815599/exclude-files-from-the-catchall-symbol

Comment: +1; good question. While your question is on-topic for Super User, there may be a better chance you'll get an answer if you post it on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com). If you so wish, you may post your question there and then delete it here. Please don't cross-post, though—having the same question on multiple sites at the same time is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Or you may flag your own question as "in need of moderator intervention" and request migration to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. I think the mods can do this for you, but am not sure.

Comment: I've added some tags. This might increase your chances of getting upvotes and an answer.

Comment: What shell are you using? `help | head -n 5` will probably tell you.

Comment: Very similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429541/how-to-tail-all-files-except-one

Comment: I will remove this question from the main stackoverflow page. thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `bash` as your shell, set the environment variable `GLOBIGNORE` to a colon-separated list of patterns which you want to *not* match when the shell is globbing, *e.g.*

```
$ export GLOBIGNORE=Repetitive.log
$ export GLOBIGNORE=somefile:anotherfile:abc*
```

---

From `man bash`:

```
   GLOBIGNORE
          A colon-separated list of  patterns  defining  the  set  of
          filenames  to be ignored by pathname expansion.  If a file-
          name matched by a pathname expansion pattern  also  matches
          one  of  the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the
          list of matches.
```

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` is your friend! If not, `find` can also help.

Here are four approaches, using `xargs`, `find ... -exec` or extended pattern matching:

**Use `xargs` via `ls` and `grep`**

```
ls | grep -v Repetitive.log | xargs tail -f
```

**Use `xargs` via `find`**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name Repetitive.log | xargs tail -f
```

**Use `find` with `-exec` argument**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name Repetitive.log -exec tail -f {} \;
```

**Use extended pattern matching in `bash`**

Great answer, taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19429723/1862762.

```
shopt -s extglob
tail -f /directory/of/logfiles/!(Repetitive.log)
```

**Note**

For this task, I would prefer the `xargs` way, as it provides output from `tail` tagged with the respective file names. Using `ls` and `grep` seems more intuitive and easy to remember.

Comment: If you need to use sudo to access the files, you can wrap the command with `sudo bash -c "<command>"`